# Маршрутизация в сети при наличии интерфейсов ethernet и wifi

Tags: linux, embedded

Разрабатываем прибор на базе ОС Linux.

На приборе установлен и настроен модуль wifi. 
Работаем в режиме точки доступа ip адрес 30.0.0.200 предположим.

Кроме этого работает ethernet. Прибор имеет ip адрес 192.168.1.200 предположим.

Внутри прибора стоит web-server обращение к которому идет по ip.

Проблема заключается в следующем: отключаем ethernet, работаем только по wifi. Но обратиться к прибору почему то можем и по  ip адресy wifi 30.0.0.200 и  ip адресy ethernet 192.168.1.200, хотя он отключен.

С чем может быть связано такое поведение? может с маршрутизацией как то?

Comment: Отключен интерфейс, а не адрес.

Comment: Адрес получается сохранен? Есть ли способ сбрасывать его? Основная цель то при отключении ethernet сделать ip ethernet недоступным для использования

Comment: когда кабель подключен, ваш прибор выступает в качестве маршрутизатора к сети, которой принадлежит адрес 192.168.1.200, для подключающихся к нему по wifi компьютеров?

Comment: *Адрес получается сохранен? Есть ли способ сбрасывать его?* Да, ухайдокать его в настройках IP-стека прибора. Например, переписать на нечто, заведомо неспособное быть IP-адресом узла, но при этом что не будет отвергнуто математикой прибора. Скажем, 0.0.0.0, 224.0.0.0 или 255.255.255.255...

Comment: alexander barakin, нет, не должен. При подключении по wifi он просто должен стать точкой доступа, выдать ip подключенному устройству (мобильному телефону например) и передавать данные. Маршрутизировать ничего не должен

Comment: Akina, Не подскажете где нужно искать настройки ip-стека?

Comment: посмотри, скорей всего  ip-forward'инг включён `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`... если маршрутизировать не должен, то просто отключи его:  `echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` — до перезагрузки... `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0" >>/etc/sysctl.conf` — перманентно.

Comment: ну, раз не должен, то и не маршрутизируйте трафик к этой сети на вашем компьютере через ваш прибор. а если **точно** не маршрутизируете (и ни один дефолтный маршрут не проложен через ваш прибор), то выясните, кто выдаёт вашему компьютеру arp-ответы про адрес 192.168.1.200. если это окажется ваш прибор, то начните с чтения [этого раздела lartc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.rpf.html)